# The order of connecting several files at one entry point

Tags: webpack

In the generated js file, the files are not glued in the order they are transferred in the array.

How to correctly specify the order of files connection??

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, "/public/src/js/entry/"),
    entry: {
        base: [
            './js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
            './js/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js',
            './js/lib/jquery/jquery.placeholder.min.js,' +
            './js/base/subscribe-mailing.js'
        ],
        indexPage: './indexPage.entry.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/dist/js'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: "public/dist/js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: '/node_modules/'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'babel-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

};
```

as a result, I need a single file with the connected ones in the order in which they are passed in the array

Answer (score 1):

Not everyone uses React... I needed to Minify CSS/JS files myself in my old projects.
Solution it's easy, just in **webpack.config.js**:

```
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'natural'
  }
```

The order will be as specified in entry **index.js**
The other useful settings here https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationmoduleids

Answer (score 0):

One way to maintain the order is to import your js files into a single js file and add it to the entry object in webpack.config.js like below

```
./src/index.js

import jquery from './js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js';
import jqueryMigrate from './js/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js';
import jqueryPlaceholder from './js/lib/jquery/jquery.placeholder.min.js';
import baseSubscribe from './js/base/subscribe-mailing.js';
```

```
./webpack.config.js


const path  = require("path");
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        indexPage : "./src/index.js",
    },
    output :{
        filename : '[name].js',
        path : path.resolve(__dirname,"public/dist/js")
    },
    module :{
        rules : [
            {
                test : /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test : /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You could inject jquery into all of your js files (globally) by adding jquery to plugins object in `webpack.config.js`.

if you use below configuration, you can directly access `jQuery` library from any js file or html using `$` or `jQuery`

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
        })
    ],
```

### Updated

Babel orders all the imports in ascending order

```
'./js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js';
'./js/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js';
'./js/lib/jquery/jquery.placeholder.min.js';
'./js/base/subscribe-mailing.js';
```

In your case, i believe that your bundled javascript file(generated by webpack) would have recorded the files in below ordering

1. subscribe-mailing
2. jquery-1.11.1.min.js
3. jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
4. jquery.placeholder.min.js

#### Now....

i could think of one solution to achieve your intended result.
This may not be the best solution, but i believe this works.

Create four js files and import each of your libraries into these 4 js files.
Name these 4 js files in ascending order

```
./src/Ajquery.js
import jquery from './js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js';

./src/Bjquerymigrate.js
import jqueryMigrate from './js/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js';

./src/CjqueryPlaceholder.js
import jqueryPlaceholder from './js/lib/jquery/jquery.placeholder.min.js';

./src/DbaseSubscribe.js
import baseSubscribe from './js/base/subscribe-mailing.js';
```

Now import all these files into `./src/index.js`

```
./src/index.js

import Ajquery from './Ajquery';
import Bjquerymigratefrom './Bjquerymigrate';
import CjqueryPlaceholderfrom './CjqueryPlaceholder';
import DbaseSubscribefrom './DbaseSubscribe';
```

*Run webpack and verify the output bundle..*

Comment: Thank's
Yes, I also tried it, and the order is not correct again =(

Comment: @АндрейСергеевич check my updated answer  and let me know your feedback...

Comment: An interesting idea, and it will work, but there are a lot of files in the project, and there are many where you need to consider the connection sequence. I would like to use normal folder names =)

Thx for trying to help

Comment: @АндрейСергеевич i'm starting to realize that the logical order in which the js files are stored in the bundle doesn't matter. why are you so much concerned about this order?

Comment: when connecting such a bundle, some libraries (those that are announced above jq in the bundle) are arguing that there is no jQuery or $

How then is it possible to solve this problem. It is important that the project uses the old jq 1.11 ?
=(

Comment: @АндрейСергеевич this problem is not due to ordering of imports. as i mentioned in my answer, use this in your webpack.config.js to inject jquery object into all of your js files.  plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
        })
    ],

Comment: @АндрейСергеевич you dont need to import jquery, to use jquery, you can add jquery to webpack plugins as i mentioned in my answer and access all jquery utility functions.webpack will inject jquery dependency into all js files in your dependency graph

Comment: @АндрейСергеевич the issue you're facing is not due to the order. the order in which js files are present in the generated bundle doesn't matter. it wouldn't cause any issue

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I already did the plugins: 'jquery' ........
it did not help, all the same, what is announced above does not see jq, but as soon as I manually move jq above for example in a bundle, everything works.
And that's not all, for example, I have an obje with translations, which should be announced above its use, and naturally when glued together, it is not in its place, and the script will fall down as soon as I move it higher with my hands - everything is ok.

Comment: It is very strange that such a strong assembly system cannot provide for such trifles as the order of connection that I pass on to him.
Thanks for the advice, but not one is not working in my situation = (
Sorry for my english

Comment: @АндрейСергеевич is it possible for you to share your code via git?

Comment: @АндрейСергеевич i dont think this is a complex issue